# Link a search interface in android to a php search page

Tags: php, android

hi im wondring if i can do something like this , i have mobile website that have two pages . one for search and the second for results . my goal is to make an android app which have a search interface exactly like the php search page . and when the options selected the results page will show up as a webview .sorry for my english 
and heres a picture to clear things up .Thanks 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWyk7.jpg
i just need a tip to replace the php search page with an android search interface .i also dont need any help in the webview part .

Answer (score 0):

You can either just set a WebView that will show the search page, which seems the more logical solution to me ( Can be achived like this : )

```
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView); 
//you can load an html code  
wv.loadData("yourCode Html to load on the webView " , "text/html" , "utf-8"); 
// you can load an URL  
wv.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Or if you insist on just having an interface which is not a WebView, you need to modify your search page to get data in some way ( using GET would be the better choice, simillar to Google) And then on player clicks search just open the webview and set your search terms, somthing like this:

```
wv.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com?q=some+text+searc+in+your+app");
```